# Getting error in python script "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'auth_none' "

Tags: python, paramiko

I am writing python script to login to ssh server using paramiko.
I wrote script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
paramiko.transport.auth_none('sachin')
ssh.connect('localhost', username='sachin', password='abc123')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('df -h')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Now getting error below
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'auth_none'

Anyone know why I am getting this error

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paramiko.transport` module does not contain a name `auth_none`, as can be seen from its [documentation](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.transport-module.html) (and from the error message as well).

Maybe you want

```
ssh.get_transport().auth_none('sachin')
```

Answer (score 2):

`auth_none` must be called on a specific `Transport` instance, not on the `transport` module.

Since the SSHClient doesn't have an equivalent, you'll have to use the raw [`Transport`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html) instead.